# Call a PHP function from HTML in the same document to hide image code

Tags: php, html

So I am learning HTML , CSS and basic Javascript at school but i'm also trying to learn PHP in my spare time. I made a meme website as a joke but it got pretty big in my school. A friend suggested I make it so people cant steal the memes. I learnt the no-right-click thing in javascript but they can still see the images in the code. so after some research PHP seemed to be the answer. I successfully used this on it's own [here](http://cgscomputing.com/40955/home/meme/test.php)
code used:

```
>     <?php
>     header('Content-type: image/png');
>     readfile("pepe.png");
>     ?>
```

but i found out you can't use the PHP inline with the HTML.
So this didn't work on the full meme page. I turned it into a .php and inserted the code on top in the function called meme1. The line full of "A"s is where I need the image to appear(by calling the function "meme1"). The test meme page php is [here](http://cgscomputing.com/40955/home/meme/index1.php) and a snippet of the source code is here:

```
<?php
function meme1(){
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  readfile("pepe.png");
}
?>

     <div class="meme-tile">
       <h2 class="exotic-title">EXOTIC TEST</h2>
       <!--AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA-->
       <div class="meme-classification exotic"><strong>Classification:</strong> Exotic</div>
     </div>


     <div class="meme-tile">
       <h2 class="exotic-title">EXOTIC: COMING SOON</h2>
       <img class="meme-image" src="images/soon.png" alt="image unavailable" />
       <div class="meme-classification exotic"><strong>Classification:</strong> Exotic</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: first and foremost, anything you display in html is readable, next you cant display image like that in html. using php readfile, if that was really a viable options major stockphoto sites would have used that method!

Comment: _“A friend suggested I make it so people cant steal the memes”_ – tell that friend, that they have clearly no idea how websites and the internet work. Stop listening to them. Stop trying to implement this nonsense. Remove the no right click nonsense, which has only ever decreased the usability of any website that used it massively while achieving exactly nothing at the same time. Go learn some more basics, and realize that you can’t output the image and the HTML code at the same time and in the same request (unless you “inline” the image, using a Data URI.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the possibility of having your images stolen. Once the image is seen by a user, it exists on **his** computer, there, he can theoretically manipulate the information in absolutely every way he thinks about.

The most simple way to *steal* your image is to make a screenshot and then simply cut the meme. So, as long as you show the image, that can be borrowed.

One solution would be to add a watermark to the image with some text to point to your site, the way that stock photo sites are trying to protect their images

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this would provide any actual prevention of downloads, as you are running into a logical problem here - you want your users browsers to be able to view (thus download) the image, but you want to make it difficult for the users to reupload the images elsewhere. After all - they could always just do a screenshot.

But to answer your question, what you want to do is to have an HTML img-tag that loads your image as so:

```
<img src="http://cgscomputing.com/40955/home/meme/test.php" />
```

You could consider specifying the src as a relative URL, leaving out the domain name and path for simplicity:

```
<img src="test.php" />
```

An alternative to this - which will also make the stealing of images a little trickier, but in no way impossible is the use of data URIs (see https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/10/27/data-uris-explained/) - here you basically embed the image in the HTML, which means that the image has no URL that someone could download the image from.

I would highly encourage you to consider publishing your works under a creative commons license instead of trying to prevent them from being shared: https://creativecommons.org/choose/ .. this way you can give people permission to share the works, if they remember to tell that you made them.

Answer (score 0):

It's **impossible** to do that.
There will be **always a way to steal your content**. I know this isn't not the answer you want, but it's the truth.